# Automatically update working copy from SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

A coworker and I are looking for a way to automatically update our working copies of a SVN repo we work on. I realize this isn't something a lot of people would be interested in but I was just wondering if a solution exists for this scenario.

Ideally the way it would work is it would just check the repository at some interval and when it sees a change in the repo and there's no local conflict it would just download the file.

If something like that isn't possible, would it be possible to at least have an icon appear on the folder/file to let you know the repo has been changed. A lot like the way an icon appears if your working copy has been edited.

Is any of this possible with a 3rd party software or another version-control system even?

Comment: You could probably scriptify that task and put it on a task schedule to check (cron or Windows Task Scheduler), otherwise you'd probably be looking for a *push* type of system that pushes updates to you, which isn't available on any revision control system, AFAIK.  As far as scriptifying, there are obvious things you would run into such as handling when there are conflicts and setting up an alert or auto-response system.  [Python](http://python.org) may be an easy way to do that (iterate through lines in stdout looking for conflict alerts using the `subprocess` module).

Comment: @nerdwaller Thanks for the tips, definitely a lot more involved than what we were hoping for. Thought there might be third party software out there, didn't think we're the only ones looking for something like this.

Comment: You probably aren't the only ones, I'm just not seeing anything in the quick research.